# No closest element to a closed subspace of $C([0,1])$ (Axler Example 8.27)

Tags: measure-theory

There's just one claim in an example from Axler's Measure Theory text which I don't understand. See Example 8.27 below.

> [image]

#### Analysis

So for any $g \in U$, it claims that
$$ \tag{1} \int_0^1 (f-g) = \frac 1 2$$
and
$$ \tag{2} (f-g)(1) = 0$$

implies that $||f - g || > \frac 1 2$.

I see that (note that I include absolute values)
$$
\int_0^1 |f-g| = \frac 1 2 \le \sup_{[0,1]} |f-g|
$$

which implies that $\text{distance}(f,U) \ge \frac 1 2$.

#### Question

But how does the condition in $(2)$ makes this inequality strict?

Comment: The functions $f,g$ are continuous so $|f(x)-g(x)|\leq1/4$ for all $x\in[1-\epsilon,1]$ for some small $\epsilon\in(0,1)$. Assuming that $\lVert f-g\rVert \leq1/2$ we get that $\int_0^1|f-g|=\int_0^{1-\epsilon}|f-g|+\int_{1-\epsilon}^1|f-g|\leq(1-\epsilon)/2+\epsilon/4<1/2$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @jakobdt Your assumption that the distance is $\le \frac 1 2$ implies that the integral is $\le \frac 1 2$. Why is there a contradiction if the integral is $< \frac 1 2$?

Comment: No, my calculation shows that the integral is $<1/2$. The point is that because $f-g$ is small near $1$, it must compensate by being large somewhere else, if we want the integral to be $=1/2$. But this is not possible if you assume that $\lVert f-g\rVert\leq 1/2$.

Comment: Oh now I see! The first term in the first inequality, $(1- \epsilon)/2$ is from your assumption, which leads to a contradiction. Your proof is now perfectly clear, thank you!